# Загрузить изображение в React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, изображения, webpack, assets

Мне нужно загрузить локальный JPG-файл, путь к которому передаётся через props компонента. Пытаюсь это сделать, используя `require`, но изображение не показывается. Выведя полученный объект в консоль, обнаружил, что был получен модуль:

```
Module {default: "/ff5a7601c48dcb99c92acfca45eb2439.png", __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

Если же загружаю изображение через `import`, то путь оказывается правильным:

```
/fa8b72877658d9175b437ebb88e3ef2c.jpg
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `require` импортирует изображение как модуль, или в чём-то другом? Как её исправить? Привожу JSX моего компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

import '../../../resources/scss/style.scss';

class ArticleCard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const { article } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={require(article.imagePath)} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{article.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{article.description}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default ArticleCard;
```

и webpack.config.js:

```
{
   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|jpg)$/i,
   use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
         name: 'client/resources/images/[name].[ext]',
         outputPath: 'dist/img/',
      },
   },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Можно просто извлечь путь из свойства `default` объекта, который возвращает `require` и вставлять его непосредственно в `src`

```
<img src={require('path/to/img.png').default} />
```

Comment: То есть, вы создали модуль из ссылки, а затем извлекли ссылку из созданного модуля и вставили это в src? Вы лучше попробуйте без дополнительных манипуляций... `<img src='path/to/img.png' />`

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, а зачем вам require? Содержание атрибута src, в который потом выльется пропс src, - это просто валидная ссылка. Уберите require-обертку, все должно заработать